# Put numbers from vector to vector<vector>> if two number's difference is 1

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

I have a problem with this code snippet and i can't realise what i did wrong.

The error output is like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Documents/feladat.cpp:18:7: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
                                b[i, j] = b[a[i + 1], a[i]];
                                  ^
/storage/emulated/0/Documents/feladat.cpp:19:9: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__ndk1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'vector<vector<int> >')
                                cout<<b;
                                ~~~~^ ~
/data/data/ru.iiec.cxxdroid/files/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/ostream:218:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector<vector<int> >' to 'const void *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
    basic_ostream& operator<<(const void* __p);
```

And it goes on with different types in the ()s

It would be a program which makes pairs into the `b` vector, if two number's difference is `1`.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    vector<vector<int>> b;
    b.reserve(10);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    for (i < a.size(); i++;)
    {
        for (j <= a.size(); j++;)
        {
            if (a[i + 1] - a[i] == 1)
            {
                b[i, j] = b[a[i + 1], a[i]];
                cout << b;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `b[i, j] = b[a[i + 1], a[i]];` where did you read that syntax? It's utterly incorrect

Comment: I used it freq. In c# thats why i tried to use it here as well :|

Comment: Access elements in a vector of vectors is `a[i][j]` not `a[i, j]`.

Comment: Please learn the difference between [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) for vectors.

Comment: As for the error, there's no standard output operator `<<` for vectors.

Comment: If an vector has 10 elements, the valid indices are 0 through 9 inclusively. You can't access element 10, there isn't one. You will be trying to access out of bound elements in your loop.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to take a couple of steps back, [get a couple of good books to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), and start over?

Comment: Just started learning a month ago, but i was trying to do some excersises. Thanks for the help tho :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 problems in given code snippet:

1. This is not how you index a 2D array: `b[i, j]`. You index it by `b[i][j]`. Otherwise, you are using a [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work/19198977) to compute a **single** index (`b[i, j]` would be equivalent to `b[j]`).
2. `for` loops are in the form of `for (initialization;comparison;increment)`. Some parts can be empty, but semicolons **must** be there. Hence `for (i < a.size(); i++;)` should be `for (;i < a.size(); i++;)`, or, alternatively `for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++;)`. The same for `j` loop.
3. Undefined behavior due to indexing (potentially unallocated) space of `b`. If you want to create 10 elements, of each vector, so you could use `operator[]`, consider just allocating all of those elements via `vector<vector<int>> b (10, vector<int> (10));` (or, alternatively (`vector<vector<int>> b (a.size (), vector<int> (a.size ()));`) instead of using `reserve`. `reserve` should be used to prevent multiple re-allocations due to multiple `push_back`s.

   **Note**, such change would make the loop `for (;j <= a.size(); j++;)` index invalid ranges of vector, due to it going through the values of `[1, 10]`, while the vector would contain valid indices of `[0, 9]`. You may change either the loop condition, or indexing (to, for example: `b[i][j-1] = b[a[i + 1]-1][a[i]-1];`).
4. `std::vector` doesn't have `operator<<`, which can be used for printing, defined. You would need to decide how would you want for the `vector` to be printed, and then define the function, which implements such printing.